# a query to check value in other table - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have below tables

[image]

**[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M9i-Qd6U)**

In `x_table`, I have different records. I want to fetch all currencies from `x_table` where continent is `Asia` which is straight forward as below,

> 1. SELECT currency from x_table where continent='Asia'

and it should return `Rupee` and `Yen` rows which is also fine.

Now look at `type` columns in `x_table` and then another `y_table` table. `type` value represents different columns in `y_table`

Now query should be (considering two tables)

Fetch all currencies from `x_table` where `continent` is `something` BUT check relative `type` column in `y_table`. If respective `type` column value is 1 then and then fetch the record otherwise ignore it.

something like

> SELECT continent, currency FROM x_table as X inner join y_table as Y on X.continent = Y.continent (BUT check if matching "type" column value is 1) if it is 0 ignore it.

With this logic, if you consider **1.** query again, it should return only `Rupee` row because `Rupee_Dual` in `y_table` for `Asia` cotinent is `1`.
But `Yen` row should not return because `Yen_Single` in `y_table` for `Asia` continent is `0`.

Comment: Have you tried a simple where clause? If so what was unsatisfactory about it? NB please add sample data as text which we can use as opposed to images which we can't.

Comment: Not that simple then -  can y_table contain an unknown/infinite number of currencies ? if so you should redesign to 1 row per continent and type

Comment: so `y_table` only contains boolean value. It must be either 0 or 1.

Comment: It's misleading that the fiddle(and the raw data) looks nothing like the published image(which is what I looked at first)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/M9i-Qd6U

Comment: I am also surprised that type generates at all given it's based on a column generated in the same select and I don't know how safe that is

Comment: @P.Salmon: `type` is in a sub select, not in the same select.

Comment: This is a very bad data model. In table_x the currency is considered data, but in y_table you make it part of the database structure. Don't do this. Don't mix the two concepts. A currency should be data, just like continents and countries.

Comment: And talking of database design, why is USA/Canada a country? It is not. These are two countries. They don't share a currency either. They only share a currency name. You may want to reconsider the whole database model. Start with a continent table. Then have a country table refering to the countries' continents. Then it seems you want a currency_name table, so a country can also be linked to a currency name. Once you have a proper database design, writing queries gets easier.

Comment: What is the question? PS [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Also: Put what is needed to ask in your post, not just at link, including a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT x_table.*,
       CASE LOCATE('/', x_table.country) 
           WHEN 0
           THEN 'Single'
           ELSE 'Dual'
           END AS country_count,
       CONCAT(x_table.name,
              '_',
              (SELECT country_count)
              ) AS type,
       CASE (SELECT type)
            WHEN 'Rupee_Single' THEN y_table.Rupee_Single
            WHEN 'Rupee_Dual' THEN y_table.Rupee_Dual
            WHEN 'Dollar_Single' THEN y_table.Dollar_Single
            WHEN 'Dollar_Dual' THEN y_table.Dollar_Dual
            WHEN 'Yen_Single' THEN y_table.Yen_Single
            WHEN 'Yen_Dual' THEN y_table.Yen_Dual
            END AS enabled                  
FROM x_table
JOIN y_table USING (continent)
-- WHERE continent = 'Asia'
-- HAVING enabled
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/ce9Q4NEX

Comment: In your result set, it returns  1) `Dollar` row which is wrong because where clause should filter only 'Asia' continent records. 2) it returns 0 or `Yen` row (record) also but since its value is 0, you query should have returned only `Rupee` row.

Comment: If I don't define where condition, it should return all the currencies with value `1`. `0` value records will be eliminated.

Comment: @micronyks Is it really so difficult to uncomment the conditions? https://dbfiddle.uk/JpNJ8R2T

Comment: I didn't observe at first place. This is exactly what I need but need to do some more testing with real DB. Thanks for your answer and help.

Comment: @micronyks My goal is not to solve your task but show how it was solved, how it works. You must study on it. PS. I strongly recommend you to pay attention on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74231391/10138734) provided by [Joop Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984823/joop-eggen). Structure normalization may greatly simplify your work.

Answer (score 3):

Mapping a value to a column name is not inherent part of the relational algebra of SQL. Meaning: better not done.

Instead make an other table instead y_table

#### y_table'

A column `value` probably not needed.

| continent | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Asia | Rupee_Single | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Then the SQL is no problem.